# Incomprehensible output using passwd distractedly

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-gnome, syntax

With little attention, after doing operations as root on an ext HDD, instead of using the correct command to disable root, I used this syntax

```
sudo -l passwd
```

I got this output

```
/usr/bin/passwd
```

I know from the man pages *passwd*, but I don't understand this result, since the syntax I've used seems nonsense to me.  Can you please explain the logic behind this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you need is in the man page for `sudo` (emphasis mine):

```
     -l, --list  If no command is specified, list the allowed (and forbidden)
                 commands for the invoking user (or the user specified by the
                 -U option) on the current host.  A longer list format is used
                 if this option is specified multiple times and the security
                 policy supports a verbose output format.

                 If a command is specified and is permitted by the security
                 policy, the fully-qualified path to the command is displayed
                 along with any command line arguments.  If command is speci‐
                 fied but not allowed, sudo will exit with a status value of
                 1.
```

So, `sudo -l` is telling you that your user is permitted to execute `/usr/bin/passwd`.